# Stored Procedure getting unique numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

So I have two stored procedure on my SQL server. One selects a number from my table, and the other increase selected cell number by one.

Currently there is only one caller to the SP, but there may be more in the future.

So I'm wondering if I have multiple callers (All the same account) to the SP, Am I at risk of getting the same number multiple time?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467353/sql-server-stored-procedures-do-they-queue-up) makes me believe that this is a possibility, but also not because I'm also editing data and the server will not try to edit data from multiple calls.

My current SP:

dbo.GetNextNumber

```
USE [NumberProvider]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetNextNumber]    Script Date: 30.3.2020 08:58:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextNumber]  
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
        @SchemeId int 

    AS  
    BEGIN  
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
        SET NOCOUNT ON; 

        -- Select next number.
        SELECT NextNum
        FROM dbo.NumberingSchemes
        WHERE Id = @SchemeId

        -- Increase number by one.
        EXEC dbo.UpdateNumber @SchemeId
    END
```

dbo.UpdateNumber

```
USE [NumberProvider]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateNumber]    Script Date: 30.3.2020 09:13:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateNumber]  
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
    @SchemeId int  

AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Update number
    UPDATE dbo.NumberingSchemes
    SET NextNum = NextNum + 1
    WHERE Id = @SchemeId
END
```

So I'm thinking that something like this is better?

```
USE [NumberProvider]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateNumber]    Script Date:
27.3.2020 21:10:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateNumber]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SchemeId int

AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SAVE TRANSACTION MySavePoint;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE dbo.NumberingSchemes
    SET NextNum = NextNum + 1
    WHERE Id = @SchemeId



     SELECT NextNum
     FROM dbo.NumberingSchemes
     WHERE Id = @SchemeId;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MySavePoint; -- rollback to MySavePoint
        END
    END CATCH
END
```

Edit 1:

To clarify, I'm using this to create numbering schemes that an external application uses distribute unique numbers. I only need to keep track of the next number that is going to be given.

This is my table design and I may need to add other schemes to the table.

[Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM9oT.png)

Comment: Why not use the built in SEQUENCE object? don't roll your own auto-increment - it will either fail or cause deadlocks (or both).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I added a small clarification. I'm creating numbering schemes that distribute unique numbers when called.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you wouldn't use a `SEQUENCE`, @Einir .

Comment: @ZoharPeled So sorry I was reading about the completely wrong thing. Yes this is so much simpler then what I was doing. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that neither a sequence nor an identity column are unique by definition - Sequences can be recycled and identity columns can be reseeded.